# While Loop in click function with different Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an accept and reject button for my project. What I need is create a click function in a while loop. So far I've done it with one I.D

Here's my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var but = "#accept-friend-button";
    var rej = "#reject-friend-button"; //When I add this
    while(i <=<?php echo $rqst_count; ?>)
    {
        $(but + i).click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(rej + x).hide(); // When I add this

        });
    i++;
    x++;
    }
});
```

So far they've work, but when I add (rej + x).hide(); The (#reject-friend-button) doesn't hide. Also what if I was to add three I.Ds for this while loop

Here's the HTML code is anyone needs it

```
        <?php
    $rqst__count = $query -> rowCount();
    $button = 1;
    $an_button = 1;
    while($row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {               
    ?>


        <button id="accept-friend-button<?php echo $button;?>" 
        style="margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;"
        class="btn btn-info">Accept
        </button>


        <button id="reject-friend-button<?php echo $an_button; ?>" 
        class="btn btn-danger">Reject
        </button>






    <?php
    $button++;
    $an_button++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you bind the click using a class instead of an id you don't need the loop.

Comment: Try 
$(but + i).on("click", function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(rej + x).hide();
});